# Find the curvature of the ellipse by the explicit equation $y=\pm\frac{b}{a}\sqrt{a^2-t^2}$

Tags: geometry, curvature

> Find the curvature of the ellipse
>   $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$
>   at the point $P=(a,0)$.

Let $x=t$ and $y=f(t)=\pm\frac{b}{a}\sqrt{a^2-t^2}$

I want to find the curvature, $\kappa$, of the ellipse at $P$. I already found that $$\kappa=\frac{|f''(t)|}{[1+(f'(t))^2]^{3/2}}$$ 
and then it should be 
$$\frac{ba^4}{[(bt)^2-(at)^2+a^4]^{3/2}}$$
But the first derivative is 
$$f'(t) = \mp\frac{b}{a}t\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-t^2}}$$ 
and the second derivative is 
$$f''(t)=\mp\frac{b}{a}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-t^2}}\mp\frac{b}{a}t^2\frac{1}{(a^2-t^2)^{3/2}}$$

If I put $t=a$ into the equation, $0$ will be in the denominator! Why?

Comment: What’s the slope of the tangent to the ellipse at $t=a?$. Draw it if you need to.

Comment: I know that the tangent line at p is $x=a$ because the tangent does not exist.

Comment: My question is when I solve it with the conclusion $\frac{ba^4}{[(bt)^2-(at)^2+a^4]^{3/2}}$, it would be $\frac{a}{b^2}$. But it doesn't make sense in $\kappa=\frac{|f''(t)|}{[1+(f'(t))^2]^{3/2}}$. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Well, if $f'(a)$ is undefined, then why do you expect any expression that involves it to be defined?

Comment: Ok, I understand

Comment: Good. This is an artifact of your parameterization. If you use a different parameterization for which the derivatives are defined everywhere, you shouldn’t run into this issue. The radius of the osculating circles at the vertices is equal to the [semi-latus rectum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Semi-latus_rectum_l) length, so you have a way to check your solution at those points.

Comment: @Maggie: Simplify your derivatives, combine them into the final curvature formula, and simplify further. The problematic factors will cancel, leaving $a^4b/(\cdots)$, into which you may substitute $t=a$ without impunity. (Note that this is actually an exercise in taking limits. The derivative pieces of the curvature formula resist direct substitution of $t=\pm a$, but we know that the curvature formula works *everywhere else*. So, we take the limit of the formula as $t$ *approaches* $a$. And, it just happens that after algebraic simplification, taking the limit reverts to direct substitution.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that neither ${dy\over dx}$ nor ${d^2y\over dx^2}$ is defined at $t=\pm a$: the tangents to the ellipse are vertical there. The expression that you have for the curvature is then also undefined at these points. Sometimes you can get lucky and these “infinities” cancel, but this isn’t one of those cases. You also haven’t defined the values of $t$ for which you use the positive or negative square root in your parameterization. The expression $\pm\frac ba\sqrt{a^2-t^2}$ is not a well-defined function of $t$. Fixing that isn’t going to make the bigger problem of undefined derivatives go away, though.

To get an expression for the curvature that works everywhere, you need to choose a parameterization for which the derivatives are defined everywhere and don’t vanish simultaneously. You can then use the formula $$\kappa = {x'y''-x''y'\over(x'^2+y'^2)^{3/2}}.$$ Try the standard parameterization $(a\cos t,b\sin t)$.